# how to change heroku path?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have installed latest version of heroku and when i type command "heroku version" gives me error "This is the legacy Heroku CLI. Please install the new CLI from https://cli.heroku.com" .. and  when i typed command "which heroku" i found that heroku points to wrong path not the path heruko had installed in it .. and i want to Know how to change heroku path to make heroku points to the file it is intalled in it ???

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$ heroku config:set PATH=~/bin
```

Comment: I tried and it does not work and said "  !    Error: No app specified
 !    Usage: heroku config:set --app APP
 !    We don't know which app to run this on.
 !    Run this command from inside an app folder or specify which app to use wit                           h --app APP
 !
 !    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app-commands

Comment: reread your question and remember incurring the error message, did you download the new cli?